# Iframes problem in Safari & Chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome, safari, xss

I have domain A that opens an IFRAME with domain B, which opens IFRAME with domain A in order to access the parent.parent.

I am able to do JS functions from A, except for SAFARI & Chrome.

I have the Iframe DOM element, and I do iframe.contentWindow.location but it doesn't give me the right domain! (gives me domain B)

What can I DO? thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's just because you do contentWindow for iframe from domain B. To get A you should do smth like `document.getElemenetsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElemenetsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location` (note that I didn't test it)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, that the iframe needed to be opened in runtime and not in the HTML. (the iframe + the src in runtime)